# ElasticSearch match query and filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a filter in ElasticSearch, but I end up getting no results back.  I can filter somewhat using a query with match, but I would rather use filter, so that I can use nested AND and OR clauses.

Here is an example.  It is an example that selects some records with a match query, the ones where `eventType` is `EiffelArtifactNewEvent`.  I've added a filter line marked `(* THIS LINE *)` that I thought would accomplish the same thing, but it turns out I get no results back.

How should I write so that I only use filter for the query-logic, and only use the query `{"match_all":{}}`?

```
{
   "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
          'match': {'eventType': {'operator': 'and', 'query': 'EiffelArtifactNewEvent'}}
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          { "term" : {"eventType" : "EiffelArtifactNewEvent"  }  (* THIS LINE*)
          (* here I will later add more AND and OR clauses *)
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And `eventType` does contain that term `EiffelArtifactNewEvent`? What's the mapping of `eventType`?

Comment: eventType is just a string. Note that the query match works fine but the filter does not, and I thought they would match the same records but they don't. Why?